# reading text with two different encoding types using ftfy

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm attempt to read text which have mixed encoding types using python ftfy library. This library give good results when text not mixed i.e

```
>>> print(ftfy.fix_text('uÌˆnicode'))
ünicode
```

But if text is mixed then got something like this i.e

```
>>> print(ftfy.fix_text('Hi to ℙℽ☂ℌϕℿ uÌˆnicode'))
ℙℽ☂ℌϕℿ uÌˆnicode
```

Is this something that this library can't handle? Is there any way to read text with mixed encoding types? Also I do some read up about python and unicode but didn't find good example how to deal when text have different encoding types.

Comment: Thanks for making me know this library, btw!

Comment: Yep, it's look useful library...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#ftfy.fix_text), `ftfy` works line by line. So within one line, it won't apply more than one encoding fix.

It works as expected if the portions with different original encoding are on different lines:

```
>>> print(ftfy.fix_text('Hi to ℙℽ☂ℌϕℿ \nuÌˆnicode'))
Hi to ℙℽ☂ℌϕℿ 
ünicode
```

Comment: Shadow, if my answer helped you solve your problem, you can "accept" it by clicking the check mark below the vote arrows.

Comment: Of course that's helped...I just wondering what if we have a file with this mixed encoding types and used python to do read up that file, some text inside need to be encoded with utf-8 and some with other encoding types. How to deal when text have different encoding types?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. You cannot actually have a single piece of text (a file, stream, string...) with multiple encodings. The snippet you show here is "broken"; this might happen if some text was decoded with the wrong choice of encoding and then concatenated with a correctly decoded string. `ftfy` can help you fix this, but only if there are newline characters between the different portions.